# Smallest rectangular prism that contains a parallelpiped spanned by three given vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given three (non-zero) linearly independent vectors $u, v, w$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and form the parallelpiped spanned by these three vectors. Is there a way to compute the dimensions of the smallest rectangular prism that contains this parallelpiped?

In two dimensions, if we're given two vectors $v, w$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the parallelogram spanned by these two vectors is contained in a rectangle with length $\|v + w\|$ and height equal $2\|w - \mathrm{proj}_{v + w}(w)\|$ where $\mathrm{proj}_{v + w}(w)$ is the projection of $w$ onto $v + w$.

Is there a similar result in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: The 2D rectangle in your example isn't necessarily that of minimum area.